# IE11 rendering issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have been fighting with this issue for a couple of days with no solution so far. I am referring to this page that I am developing:

[www.pirallaweb.com](http://www.pirallaweb.com)

IE11 and IE10 seem to be having serious issues while rendering this page, no problem though in IE9, where animations are missing.

The problem only occurs on large monitor (mine is 2560x1440).
What I get is this:

[image: website rending issue screenshot]

For some reasons it cuts every div's content in half for no reason.
The only way to solve this issue is removing the footer but I can's see any flaw in it.

Feel free to check the code, as you can see there's very little javascript involved and that doesn't see to be the problem. I tried removing it bit by bit with no success.

Others attempts I did where adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` and adding a z-index to block, but with no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So the problem is linked to your resolution and the browser?

Comment: seems to be a bug with the text-shadow set on the `body, html`...when I uncheck it in dev tools, it renders correctly

Comment: Yes, it does not appear when I stretch the window so that it's smaller than my fullscreen

Comment: @Ted what the hell, you're right :o

Comment: You are positioning a lot. Would suggest to use floats.

Comment: Glad to help :) IE doesn't always get along so well with those effects

Comment: @Ted that seems like a nasty bug though. When I face these issues I wonder how many others are ready waste my time >.<